# How do you lock a thread in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a method that calls an `async` method inside of it. How Can I lock the main thread until my completion handler of the `async` method is done?

Comment: The idea of using threads is so you don't have you lock the main thread, wouldn't this be breaking those conventions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **never lock main thread**, it's a really bad user experience -- just disable the entire UI (is that what you mean?). Something like

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

and re-enable it after the async operation finishes:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

But remember to show an activity indicator, or some indication that the app is still running.

Or consider a component like [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD).

Comment: My async method returns the data for a tableview so I need to lock it up until I have that data to populate the table.

Comment: @Deekor: Why? Why not show a loading indicator (and later update when the async call completes)?

Comment: Then just show an empty table view, or something like 'Loading...' text in the table view. And call `[tableView reloadData]` once the data comes. The table view should be able to work with empty (`nil`) data source.

Comment: Because I'm new to iOs and didnt know `[tableView reloadData]` existed. however I just tried calling it in the completion handler and it crashed the app

Comment: Nvm the crash was due to something else. This fixed it thank!

Comment: It's a different question then. What's the error? Have you hooked up your data source correctly, like implementing all the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection`, `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, etc?